# Submit a form from different page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Driver form (which is basically the user - I can do current_driver and stuff) and one of the fields is a boolean checkbox for 'subscribe to newsletter'.
I want to put this form on multiple pages that do not share the same controller, i.e Dashboard which has a pages controller.
I am using a partial to do this so i can just add the partial to a template easily.
I believe that the form should post to edit_driver_path as it's the driver form? At the moment when I submit the form, I get "No route matches [POST] "/drivers/dashboard/edit".

Am I on the right path here?

Let me know if I need to post controllers, forms or whatever.

Comment: A form can only point to one page, you can make different AJAX calls with part of the fields or you can handle that in the backend, sending all the information to one controller that splits the data to two different endpoints.

Personally I think that your logic for 'subscribe to newsletter' should be in a new class that can be called in any controller.

Comment: @javiyu thanks for your comment. Can you explain about the new class?

Comment: you can read about it here https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/refactor-ruby-rails-service-object/